# How to export a dictionary of lists to csv with no headers in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm attempting to take data in the following format (with quotation marks) and:

1) Export it to CSV
2) Add headers to the file:

```
{
9: [[0, 0, 'ABC'], [1, 2, 'DE'F'], [3, 4, 'GHI']], 
11: [[9, 30, 'LEOPAR'D'], [17, 28, 'DOG'], [19, 43, 'APP'LE']]
}
```

The data should look like this:

```
Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4
9        0        0        ABC
9        1        2        DE'F
9        3        4        GHI
11       9        30       LEOPAR'D
```

The quotation marks are also coming up as '\u2019s'

I have a file with about 900 keys, so I need a dynamic way to call the key, instead of calling in explicitly. I tried and got a 'sequence expected' error with the following code. Ideally, I would like '9' to be repeated in the csv file for each row it is associated with.

```
writefile = filepath
fieldnames = {'data1':['data2', 'data3', 'data4']}
with open( writefile, 'w' ) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(section_num_by_paragraph_num)
```

Comment: How should the resulting CSV look like for your example data?

Comment: @Jasper just updated the forum, to reflect what the output should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, but I don't understand what you mean by

> so I need a dynamic way to call the key

Please be more specific if the code below does not do what you want.

```
import csv

data = {
        9: [[0, 0, 'ABC'], [1, 2, 'DE"F'], [3, 4, 'GHI']], 
        11: [[9, 30, 'LEOPAR"D'], [17, 28, 'DOG'], [19, 43, 'APP"LE']]
       }


fieldnames = ['Field{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,5)]

with open( 'outfile', 'w' ) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', quotechar="")
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for k, vv in data.items():
        for v in vv:
            writer.writerow([k] + v)
```